# display block display none issues using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i hover on `div#new-menu-lower ul.menuul li.menuli` i want to add display block to the first ul and first li in the code below. The problem is its adding display block/none to all the ul and li.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //on hover of sub menu li then highlight itself
    $('div#new-menu-lower ul.menuul li.menuli').hover(

    function() {
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul:first').css("display","block");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li:first').css("display","block");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul:first').css("display","block");

    }, function() {
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul:first').css("display","none");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li:first').css("display","none");
        $('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul:first').css("display","none");
    })
});
```

If i hover on the 2nd UL LI then it will only show the FIRST ul li ul li and thats wrong.

I have managed to solve part of it by doing:
(it now adds `display:block` to the submenu which is - ul li ul but i it wont add it to the other elements)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //on hover of sub menu li then highlight itself
    $('div#new-menu-lower ul.menuul li.menuli').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul').css("display","block");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li:first').css("display","block");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul').css("display","block");

    }, function() {
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul').css("display","none");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li:first').css("display","none");
        $(this).children('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul').css("display","none");
    })
});
```

Comment: is it called `:first` in jquery?

Comment: Its like i need to do `display:block` on `this` element

Comment: Can you please share the jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `:first` instead of `:first-child`

or use the `>` selector